# ERB Syntax error while rendering XML element with attribute

Tags: html, ruby, xml, erb

I built an html table using XMLBuilder and here's the code for it:

```
test_table = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:indent=>2)

test_table.table {
   test_table.tr {
     hash.each do |k,v| 
       if v.class==Hash then 
         test_table.th(k,"colspan"=>"2")
         v.each do |kk,vv|
           test_table.tr { 
             test_table.td(kk)
             test_table.td(vv)
           }  
         end  
       else  
         test_table.th(k)
         test_table.td(v)
       end  
     end  
   }  
 }
```

When I try to render it using erb and templating it gives me a syntax error.

It works if I remove "colspan"="2" from test_table.th(k,"colspan"="2"), but I kinda need to specify that attribute for the table header.

Here's what I do in my erb html template to display the table:

```
<%= "#{test_table}" %>
```

and here's the screenshot of the error:

[image: error]

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround to the issue?

Comment: Is that your actual code? The above syntax is valid. `"colspan"=>"2"` does not even contain an integer. A line that would produce such a syntax error is `test_table.th(k,"colspan"=>"2"3)` (note the `3` after `"2"`). Please double check your code.

Comment: Checked again; yes that's the code. Added a screenshot of the error, if that helps.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the rest of your ERB template, and perhaps the code that renders it? (As an aside, there's never any reason to do `"#{foo}"`. Just use `foo` directly or, if you're not sure `foo` is a string and you need it to be a string, `foo.to_s`. The latter is not the case here, though, since ERB will automatically call `to_s`.)

Comment: Just changed "#{foo}" to foo, and it worked! Is it possible that the quotation marks were causing a problem?